# Is there snmp library source code with a clear separation from platform code

Tags: snmp

Do you know a professional implementation of the SNMP protocol with a clear separation from the underlying system?

I tried to compile the net-snmp lib and also snmp++-3.3.9 lib on my TI DSP platform where pthread functions are not available because of another Real-time operating system, where socket functions have a different API and where a lot of systems functions are not available or with a different API.
Both compilation trials result in a big mess of errors because the system stuff is spread all over the code without abstraction layer.

That is why I need a clear abstraction layer of all those underlying system stuff, clearly separated from the SNMP protocol stuff, a generic stub which I can connect to my RTOS and platform code. Can you help me, please?

Comment: What you are looking for sounds like a castle in the sky.

Comment: @Lex Li: clear separation of abstraction layers should be default for a maintainable programming style, this is a common software requirement not a castle in the sky

Comment: You have done your homework and checked vendor products, and already known that many are platform specific and do not have platform abstraction layer. Well, you might come across some vendor that meets your criteria, but this is not a "common" thing. Unnecessary abstraction only increases the complexity without adding significant value. As netsnmp and snmp++ are open source, you can create your own forks.